# How to classify singularities of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been trying to understand complex analysis but can't figure out how to classify singularities of a function. For example I am stuck on the following question:

Classify the singularities of the function:

$f(z) = \dfrac {\sin(z^2)}{(\sin z)^2}\ $

Im thinking this has singularities at $z= n\pi$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True. $A=\{n \pi, n \in \Bbb Z\}$ is the set of singularities of $A$.

Each $n \pi$ is an isolated singularity since $f$ is analytic on the punctured disk $D(n\pi, 1) \setminus \{n \pi\}$ (for instance).

We have $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z) = 1$, so $|f|$ is bounded in the punctured disk $D(0, 1) \setminus \{0\}$ (on which $f$ is analytic). Hence $0$ is a removable singularity of $f$.

Otherwise, for $n \neq 0$, $\sin((n\pi)^2) \neq 0$ and $z \mapsto \sin^2 z$ has a zero of order $2$ at $n \pi$. Hence, each $n \pi$ for $n \neq 0$ is a pole of order $2$ of $f$.